# Position relative overlaps float-left

Tags: css, css-float, css-position, overlap

For a back-end solution of a CMS exclusively, I wanted to enable the user to switch any CMS element to `float: left` on purpose. However, I had to find that as all my container elements also use relative positioning, any element that is placed next to a floated one, will overlap that one (only as a block, not by content) and thus render the user incapable of using any of the other elements controls.

```
<div id="container1" class="elContainer" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="container2" class="elContainer" style=""></div>

.elContainer {
   position: relative;
}
```

You can try this JSFiddle setup to test the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/PNktA/
If you remove the float from the first outer container, you will be able to click the edit button. If you keep the float, you cannot click it.

I tried to find a solution that works here, but I failed in doing so. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

It is alright if the solution works in FF and Safari only, as I can demand usage of those browsers for my back-end.

Comment: Or even better, a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Demo (I *think* this shows OP's CSS problem): http://jsfiddle.net/6XbAm/

Comment: I created this to demonstrate the issue: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PNktA/) ... if you remove the float from the first outer container, you will be able to click the edit button. If the float remains active, you can't

Comment: I think we need to see the full markup including the containing div.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen you'd posted a demo when I added that last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a higher z-index on the first elContainer element than the second you can then click the edit control successfully.

Comment: Thank you for this hint! It is correct, but i'm afraid it is a solution i cannot apply to my system (even though it definitely is a good solution!). I just wonder whether there are other ways to deal with this issue.

Comment: ah that's a shame thought I had nailed it there!

Comment: In fact, sir, you did. I managed to integrate it by simply decrementing a z-index variable for each set in my renderer module.

Comment: Great! (oh and by the way I am not a sir :) )

Answer (score 3):

*Brighty* has already provided a solution, but perhaps I could explain why the "problem" is actually happening.

As far as I've understood, it's related to bullet point 1, and because of point 2:

1. *Positioned* elements are placed *above floating non-positioned* siblings.
2. Elems that appear **later** in the rendering tree are **painted above** their earlier siblings.

In your example, the `.elContainer` with the red box is actually positioned. So rule 1 above does not apply, but I included it anyway because it's useful to know. However, the `.elContainer` with the red box  appears *before* the `.elContainer .someTextBlock` in the source / rendering tree, and therefore the text block is painted on top of the red box. If you add a `background-color` to the text box, you'll visually notice that it's painted above the red box.  See http://jsfiddle.net/PNktA/2/

Refer to rule 5 and 8 in the [W3C spec, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html)

Comment: Thank You for the input. In my case the case is closed as i implemented this using the z-index solution. There have been times at which i encountered small problems in more complex page situations, but overall it works quite fine. Back then i would have preferred another approach though.